# jQuery page pre-loader appears after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So on one of my websites I added a jQuery pre loader which works perfectly fine on all pages except my main page.
The page that is causing issues also has a slider jQuery plugin which doesn't seem to work (at first) as well. Basically it seems that for some reason jQuery plugins are only kicking in after page is fully loaded. It happens once, once page gets loaded at least one time (cached) everything works fine.
I experimented with placing scripts in head tag and before closing body tag, no difference.

You can see issue here (click left red button, after that you'll be redirected to /main.php page which is the one causing issues.)
http://freshbeer.lv

I don't think That I'll need to post any code here as I am almost certain it is something to do with positioning of jQuery files (which you can see by inspecting page), but if you think it is something different and you'd like me to post code here, please feel free to ask and I will update my question.

Comment: Its working fine for me, 'chrome osx'

Comment: @Fresheyeball I also tested it in various browsers on osx machine, but it doesn't always work as it needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have these:

```
<script src="js/placeholder.js"></script>
<script> $('input[placeholder], textarea[placeholder]').placeholder(); </script>
```

before this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

resulting in these

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined   
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

forgot about this one

```
GET http://freshbeer.lv/img/loading.gif 404 (Not Found)
```

These are all in the dev tools console. In chrome in this case, but other browsers have one too.

Comment: I moved it after jQuert library now, still no change. Can I also ask you what did you use to get errors? (what tool is that?)